# Number input validation clientside not working ASP.Net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, validation

I'm trying to do a number validation to make sure the number they are typing in is bigger then the last bet, but it is not going so well for me...

Here is the Form:

```
<div id="frmBid" class="form-inline">
    <div><p id="bidValidation" class="text-danger"></p></div>
    <input name="auctionId" value="@Model.AuctionVM.AuctionId" type="hidden" id="auctionId" />
    <label asp-for="BidVM.Amount" />
    <input id="bidInput" type="number" name="amount" /> <--- THIS I WANT TO CHECK
    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg</button>
</div>
```

Here is my attempt for a javascript function to add validation text to the div with the P tag inside it:

```
<script>
    $('#bidInput').on('keyup', function ()
    {
        if (this.value < '@Model.AuctionVM.LastBid')
        {
            $('#bidValidation').val("Budet måste vara högre än det bestående");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#bidValidation').val("");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I don't know any other way, if there is a easier one. Please tell me.
I'm pretty new to asp.net data validation client side.

And yes I'm already validating the data on the server.
But I want to make the text appear above the input.